# How to remove html tags using JavaScript and keep newline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, preg-replace

I want to remove rich text from my `contenteditable` div keep only `newline` or `br` tags when paste something from clipboard.

I'm trying but its doesn't work
http://jsfiddle.net/marco83/zkf5jkqu/

```
<div id="editableDiv" contentEditable="true" style="min-height: 200px; border: solid 1px #0099FF;"></div>

<input type="button" value="remove" onclick="strip();">

<script>
function strip() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
    var str  = mydiv.innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
    str = str.replace(/<(?:.|\s)*?>/g, "");
    mydiv.innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```

I copy the text from this page http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/
I know it doesn't have any `<br>` tag the text. but how can i do like Twitter does like this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This

```
<script>
    function strip() {
        var mydiv = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
        var str = mydiv.innerHTML;
        mydiv.innerHTML = remove_tags(str);
    }


    function remove_tags(html) {
        html = html.replace(/<br>/g, "$br$");
        html = html.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '$br$');
        var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
        tmp.innerHTML = html;
        html = tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
        html = html.replace(/\$br\$/g, "<br>");
        return html;
    }
</script>
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zkf5jkqu/2/)

So what i am doing is, i am replace `<br>` and `\n` with a placeholder `$br$` so as to preserve them and then i am removing all the HTML tags from the string and replacing `$br$` back with `<br>`

Comment: That is like a temporary storage to preserve the `<br>` and `\n`